# How to restart app after closing using "pm clear command"

Tags: android

I have to implement a function that must delete all user/cache data of my Android application, to do this I have implemented a function that I can "call" using a simple push that runs this code below:

```
String performClearData() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject jdata = new JSONObject();
    try {
        FilesUtilities fu = new FilesUtilities();
        fu.deleteFiles();

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        runtime.exec("pm clear MY.APP");
        jdata.put("Stato del comando", "Eseguito");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        wil.WriteFile("warning", "5)PushResponderEngine - Exception in PerformClearData: " + e.toString());
    }
    return jdata.toString();
}
```

Now i would know if is it possible restart the application after this command, I have tried with this code but doesn't work:

```
intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MYApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext(), 0,new 
Intent(getIntent()), getIntent().getFlags());
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000, intent);
    System.exit(2);
```

Comment: In the above code, you must set it in the function provided to Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(), see example here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/thread_setdefaultuncaughtexceptionhandler.htm

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what I must do with this code...
Could you explain the concept with one example, please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

In your StartActivity.java, you must set the Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(handler) in the onCreate() method, like this:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

final Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.context = context;
    setContentView(R.layout.start_activity);
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            StartActivity.restartApp(context);
        }
    });
    //your code here
}

public static void restartApp(Context context)
{
    Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(context, StartActivity.class); //Replace StartActivity with the name of the first activity in your app
    int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
    PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, mPendingIntentId,    mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent);
    System.exit(0);
}

}
```

When you call the android pm clear data command, you force close the application (if it is opened); [when the app gets force closed, it throws an unhandledException](http://chintanrathod.com/auto-restart-application-after-crash-forceclose-in-android/), that gets handled by the code above.

Comment: The problem is not restart the application, what i want to do is restart the app AFTER “pm clear command” (that performs a force close of the application)

Comment: No, in a function inside a class. I have implemented a function that I can "call" using a simple push